# Inserting python Lambda function into tensorflow hashtable

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow

For instance, I first constructed a dictionary which consists of some lambda function (which return complex128) in it

```
Dict = {"a":lambda x: a(x), "b":lambda x: b(x), ......}
```

After that, I tried to construct a tensorflow hashtable to contain the element in the dictionary

```
keys = list(Dict.keys())
values = list(Dict[k] for k in keys)
table  = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys,values, key_dtype=tf.string,
value_dtype=tf.complex128), -1)
```

Yet, an error pops up as

```
TypeError: Expected complex128, 
got <function <lambda> at 0xbc12d70> of type 'function' instead.
```

The error makes sense as I am passing lambda function instead of complex128 numbers. Therefore I want to ask is there a way for me it put the lambda functions in the hashtable? or a way to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Can't you just use ```{"a": a}``` instead of ```{"a":lambda x: a(x)}```?

Comment: Of course, I can, but the same problem occurs for both cases. And the dictionary is more for demonstration rather than the actual case. And there are some functions in my actual dictionary must be expressed in the lambda expression.

Comment: fyi, if you want to split a dictionary into keys-values lists, you can unroll them with `zip` like this: `..Initializer(*zip(*Dict.items()), key_dtype..)`

Comment: @Arne Thanks for that :P

Comment: I assume setting `value_dtype` to `function` is not possible, and you are trying to find a way to pass a function as a different type, right?

Comment: @Arne Yes. As the there is no function type in tensorflow (at least in my understanding).

Comment: well, there is `import types; types.FunctionType`. Will that work?

Comment: @Arne The error as follows pops up `Cannot convert value <type 'function'> to a TensorFlow DType`

Comment: Can you give an actual example of such a lambda function that is supposed to produce `complex128`s? How or when do you plan to supply the function parameters?

Comment: @Arne I was using [pycbc](https://github.com/ligo-cbc/pycbc) one of the functions that gives complex128 is pycbc.types.TimeSeries.timeslice(tstart, tend).to_frequencyseries().data, which is the Fourier transform of a segment of data. Actually, I need to construct a tensor using tensorflow while loop and part of the tensor depend on the Fourier transformed data. Therefore, I supply the function with tstart and tend (which are constant tensor) to the function through tf.py_func